# HttpResponseMessage.Content.ToString(); Comes back as System.Net.Http.SteamContent

Tags: c#, api, rest

I am trying to consume an API in C#, this is the code for the request. It should be a simple JSON API, however I'm getting some irregularities here.

```
public static HttpResponseMessage sendRequest(List<Header> headers, string endpoint, string api_key, string api_secret)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            List<Header> headerlist = new List<Header>{};

            if(headers != null)
                headerlist = headers;

            List<Header> signed = Helpers.sign(endpoint, api_secret);
            foreach (Header header in signed)
            {
                headerlist.Add(header);
            }

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.coinkite.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-CK-Key", api_key);

            foreach (Header header in headerlist)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Name, header.Data);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;

            return response;

        }


    }
```

Which I am calling via

```
HttpResponseMessage result = Requests.sendRequest(null, "/v1/my/self", api_key, api_secret);

return result.Content.ToString();
```

However, when I write that to console it looks like:

System.Net.Http.SteamContent

Any clue as to what the issue is? I am not too familiar with the stream content type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpContent does not implement ToString method. So you need to use `result.Content.CopyToAsync(Stream)` to copy the result content to a Stream.

Then you can use StreamReader to read that Stream.

Or you can use
`string resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`
to read the result as string directly.This method no need to use StreamReader so I suggest this way.

Answer (score 0):

Call [GetResponse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) on the HttpResponseMessage

```
Stream stream = result.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
return readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the contents, you can get the string directly by changing

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
```

to

```
string response = client.GetStringAsync(endpoint).Result;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx